# How can I implement a parking counter with multiple entrances and exit?

Tags: arduino-uno, project

I'm relatively new to arduino projects and am trying to solve a real world problem on a parking lot space counter. 
My Idea is to have a sensor placed on the entrances and exit to count the total number of cars in the parking lot.
Now there are several codes online but they only implement for 1 entrance.

Scaling for 4 entrances:

> Would it be ideal to implement 1 main unit with multiple cables running to each sensors placed on the entrances and exits of the parking lot.

Given that the parking lot is huge:

> Is there a wireless way to transmit data from each sensor to the central unit ?

I'm welcoming any recommendations regarding this project.

EDIT:
This is for an actual prototype. I've scoped around the garage to find that I only need  multiple entry exit (2) system for the ground floor. Rest of the two floors have their own 1 entry and exit points. 
The entrance and exit are the same point so I was thinking of a bidirectional sensor.

> Does 10 feet of width pose a problem for the sensor ? 
>   Could I instead use two bi-directional sensors placed on either sides of the entry and exit, and then hook them up to the same input in the Arduino ? So incase 1 misses the other one registers.

Edit 2: The parking deck is big enough to hold about 20-25 cars on each of the 3 floors. I don't know the exact measurement though

> Besides Sensors could I use a wire on the floor to register when a car crosses over ? Would that be easier?

Comment: Theoretically, the sum stays the same. If you count how many cars go in, and how many go out, it won't matter where they go in or go out.

Comment: Mind that if it misses one car (or the message gets lost), the counter will become offset. And the system can't really recalibrate itself. You'll probably want to have persistant/failsafe storage, to avoid the system being desynchronised after a power failure.

Comment: You could go with wireless, as long as there is bidirectional communication, you can make the counter "acknowledge" incoming or outgoing cars. If the connection is lost, you'll want to retransmit the message until it is accepted. (This may also lead to desynchronisation).

Comment: Is it for a prototype or an actual product?

Comment: personally, i would just use ESP8266s and have one host an AP that the other sensors connect to

Comment: Define "huge"..